# RecyclerView.Adapter's onBindViewHolder() is not called for last position

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, binding, android-adapter, android-viewholder

As the title says, reaching the bottom of my RecycleView does not call `onBindViewHolder()` for the last item position. The result is that after reaching the last element, if I touch the RecyclerView list it jumps to the penultimate item.

At start the issue was bigger because the positions stopped to be called several items before the last one, like 6 or 7, but it got better after changing my `ViewPager2` widget from this

```
<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
```

to this

```
<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

but still I can't understand why.

Here is the code of my Adapter:

```
public class UserListRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserListRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

    private final List<CallManagementHelper.RemoteUserInfo> mAllUsers;
    private final List<CallManagementHelper.RemoteUserInfo> mOnlineUsers;
    private final List<CallManagementHelper.RemoteUserInfo> mInProgressUsers;
    private final List<CallManagementHelper.RemoteUserInfo> mOfflineUsers;
    private final OnListFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public UserListRecyclerViewAdapter(List<CallManagementHelper.RemoteUserInfo> onlineUsers,
                                       List<CallManagementHelper.RemoteUserInfo> inProgressUsers,
                                       List<CallManagementHelper.RemoteUserInfo> offlineUsers,
                                       OnListFragmentInteractionListener listener) {
        mOnlineUsers = onlineUsers;
        mInProgressUsers = inProgressUsers;
        mOfflineUsers = offlineUsers;

        mAllUsers = new ArrayList<>();
        if (mOnlineUsers != null && mOnlineUsers.size() > 0) {
            mAllUsers.addAll(mOnlineUsers);
        }

        if (mInProgressUsers != null && mInProgressUsers.size() > 0) {
            mAllUsers.addAll(mInProgressUsers);
        }

        if (mOfflineUsers != null && mOfflineUsers.size() > 0) {
            mAllUsers.addAll(mOfflineUsers);
        }

        mListener = listener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // No need for a LayoutInflater instance since the custom view inflates itself.
        UserCellLayout userCell = new UserCellLayout(parent.getContext());
        return new ViewHolder(userCell);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: position = " + position);

        CallManagementHelper.RemoteUserInfo userInfo = mAllUsers.get(position);
        holder.getUserCellLayout().setFullName(userInfo.displayName);
        holder.getUserCellLayout().setRemoteUserIcon(userInfo.deviceType);
        holder.mView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (null != mListener) {
                mListener.onListFragmentInteraction(userInfo);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mAllUsers.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        final UserCellLayout mView;

        ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            mView = (UserCellLayout) view;
        }

        UserCellLayout getUserCellLayout() {
            return mView;
        }
    }
}
```

I already checked and my `mAllUsers.size()` has all the N elements, but the `onBindViewHolder()` always stops to be called at item N-1.

Thanks in advance to anyone stopping here to help me find a solution, if you need more informations just ask!

Answer (score 0):

use mContext instead of parent.getContext()

```
private Context mContext;

   UserListRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<CallManagementHelper.RemoteUserInfo> onlineUsers,
                                       List<CallManagementHelper.RemoteUserInfo> inProgressUsers,
                                       List<CallManagementHelper.RemoteUserInfo> offlineUsers,
                                       OnListFragmentInteractionListener listener) {
        //Your code here
        //Add this line
        this.mContext = context;
    }

 @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // No need for a LayoutInflater instance since the custom view inflates itself.
        UserCellLayout userCell = new UserCellLayout(mContext);
        return new ViewHolder(userCell);
    }
```